# Connecting relay to 220v

Tags: relay

I have the following relay: *osa-ss-212dm3*

I want to control my AC lamp which is connected directly to a 220V socket. By reading the datasheet, I found it says that its rated voltage is 240V AC and max switching voltage is 30V DC. Can I connect this relay safely into a 220V AC power socket and trigger it with 5V from my micro-controller?

Answer (score 4):

osa-ss-212dm3 relay has 12V coil. You need osa-ss-205dm5 if you want to trigger by 5V and want to switch 240V AC.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Note: you cannot feed that relay from MCU pin directly. Coil needs 540mW (it is ~110mA at 5V), so MCU will not be able to deliver such current (depends on MCU). You will have to use some switching transistor too.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
*Figure 1. Extract from datasheet.*

- The contacts are rated for 240 V AC. That looks OK.
- It will switch 3 A. That, on the face of it suggests that it could switch 240 x 3 = 720 W.
- The switching power is 300 VA, 72 W. According to Omron's [General-purpose Relay Glossary](http://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/guide/36/generalrelay_tg_e_6_1_23-32_54-59_further_info.pdf)

> **Maximum switching capacity**
>
> The maximum load capacity that can
> be switched. Design circuits to
> ensure that this value is not exceeded during operation. Maximum
> switching capacity is expressed as VA for AC relays and W for DC
> relays.

- From the above we can deduce that it's only rated for 300 VA so you could only switch 3 A at 100 V AC and at 220 V you could switch 300/220 = 1.5 A approx.
- The final problem is that if you're switching incandescent lamps the initial current at the point of switch-on could be four or five times the running current due to the filament being cold. This would limit you to a 60 W lamp.

---

> @Chupacabras has pointed out: There are 2 types. One with "DM3" and one with "DM5" at the end. DM3 (mentioned in OP) has contacts rated for 125V AC. So it is not suitable to switch 230V lamp.

I missed this. The *Max. switching voltage* of 240 V AC appears to be for both DM3 and DM5 whereas the *Contact ratings* section down lower says the DM3 is only rated for 125 V AC.

> Can I connect this relay safely into 220v AC power socket and trigger it with 5 V?

It seems not. The DM5 would be a better choice.

It will probably be fine for a 100 W lamp. The contacts are rated for 100,000 cycles at rated load. For several cycles per day on a typical domestic lamp it should last a long time even if operated slightly outside specifications on the contacts.

Comment: There are 2 types. One with "DM3" and one with "DM5" at the end. DM3 (mentioned in OP) has contacts rated for 125V AC. So it is not suitable to switch 230V lamp.

Comment: Hmmm - that's at the bottom of the extract I posted. I only saw the rating at the top. A little confusing! I'll fix it later. Thanks.